# start up error : unable to find a medium containing a live file system

Tags: boot, usb, dell, filesystem, startup

I was working on my Dell PC which had ubuntu in it and accidentally I spilled coffee on it. Then the technician opened the system and drained out & dried the coffee and now it says:

```
"unable to find a medium containing a live file system"
```

every time I turn on my PC.  When the technician used a windows installed hard disk it all works fine and the hardware seems all set. I need to recover some important files.

Comment: So far so good. Now what's your question?

Comment: Although much of your data was likely overwritten by the Windows installation, some may still exist. You may find https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery useful

Comment: @ElderGeek - It sounds like the technician used a separate HDD, not overwrote Ubuntu.

Comment: @AndroidDev If that's the case (provided the original drive isn't too badly damaged) it should be simple.

Comment: Do you have the original drive?

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to attempt data recovery:
A bootable live media, A spare drive (preferably of larger capacity than the original)

1. Prepare a live Ubuntu media (on optical or USB flash)
2. Boot from live media
3. Check to see if the system sees the original drive
4. mount the spare drive to a target location
5. create a forensic image of the original drive placing the output on the spare drive using `dd` or `dc3dd`(we will work on this image as necessary preserving and setting aside the original drive to allow for future recovery attempts in case something goes wrong)
6. mount the partition the data is on from the image
7. copy the data to a target location with sufficient space to contain the data.

If any part of this is unclear, drop me a comment telling me where you are stuck and I will elaborate as necessary.